# How to construct multipledata in a excel cell using Java

Tags: java

I am reading an excel sheet in netbeans using Java. In ONE CELL, i have multiple values in each line, like : 39N
                  98N
                  99N
                  12N and so on..

I did this,

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
    if(row.getCell(0) != NULL) {
    ..... // get all the 4 values separately
    }
}
```

I get all the 4 rows of data if its printed. But, how to get each row of data and store it separately?

Thanks
Ramm

Comment: What Excel-library are you using to read the file?

Comment: Hi, I am using poi... org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel and my excel file is xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/), you can get the String out of the cell via the [`getStringCellValue`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue%28%29) method and split it up at every whitespace (`\s` in regex) using [`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
    if(row.getCell(0) != NULL) {
        String cellContents = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        String[] splittedValues = cellContents.split("\\s");
    }
}
```

`splittedValues` would then be:

```
{
    "39N",
    "98N",
    "99N",
    "12N"
}
```